# Question of removing numbers from a loop in c++

Tags: c++, c++17

so I have a question, so I have these codes here in c++

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i += 2)
     {
          cout<<i<<"\t";
     }
    return 0;
}
```

so the result of this is all odd numbers from 1 to 100, but I want it to remove the number  `5 7 93` from the result, so how do I do that?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this problem? Please post your code attempts

Comment: `if (i != 5 && i != 7 && i != 93) { cout<<i<<"\t"; }`

Comment: Think skip, not remove

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` - Don't *ever* do that. `using namespace std` - usually also a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the loop you can do a check condition of the current loop index value and skip by using continue;

```
 for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i += 2)
 {
      if (i == 5 || i == 7 || i == 93) {
         continue;
      }
      cout<<i<<"\t";
 }
```